# Probability density function notation question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**My question:** What do the parts in red mean? I have never seen this notation before. Does this change what I have to show?

I need to determine the coefficients $C_b$ and $C_c$ (if possible) so that $f_i(x)$ satisfies the properties of a probability density function.

$$f_1(x)=C_b \left(\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\right) \cdot \color{red}{1_{(0,1)}} (x)$$

and

$$f_2(x)=C_c \left( (ax) \cdot \color{red}{\unicode[STIXGeneral]{x1D7D9}_{[0,1]}}+(-bx+a+b)\cdot \color{red}{\unicode[STIXGeneral]{x1D7D9}_{(1. \frac{a+b}{b}]}}\right)$$with $a,b>0$

I know that I need I need to show two properties:

1. $f_i(x) \ge 0 \space \forall \space x \in \mathbb R$
2. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_i(x)dx=1$

The constants will be determined by property 2.

Comment: Seems like an [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) to me.

Comment: @Eminem So does this mean that $\unicode[STIXGeneral]{x1D7D9}_{[0,1]}$ returns $1$ if the outcome of my experiment is in that interval?

Comment: It means that $f_1(x) = C_b \frac{1}{x(1-x)}$ if $x \in (0,1)$ and $f_1(x)=0$ otherwise.  These are functions of real variables, not random variables, so they don't depend on the outcome of any experiment; rather they describe the distribution of outcomes of experiments.

Comment: @user6247850 Ok that makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the indicator function. $\mathbb{I}_{\{A\}} = \mathbb{1}_{\{A\}} = \bigg\{ \begin{matrix} 1, \text{ if A} \\ 0, \text{ if not A} \end{matrix}$

One importan identity regardin the indicator function is the following:
$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_{\{X \in A\}}) =\mathbb{P}(X \in A)$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This and the comments helped me understand.

Comment: Technically, that's an indicator random variable. Although, of course, an indicator function is similar. $$\small\mathbf 1_{(0..1)}(x) = \Bbb I_{x\in(0..1)} =\begin{cases}1 &:& x\in(0..1)\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$